# How do i swap every other letter/character in Java?

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner in java and right now I've been trying to swap every other letter. For example, if the input is:
baby
I want the output to be:
abyb

But I can't seem to get that. Here is my code,

```
String str = "baby";

    int lee =0;
    int le = 0;
    for ( le = 1; le <= str.length(); le +=2) {
        System.out.print(str.charAt(le));
        for ( lee = 0; lee < str.length(); lee +=2) {
        System.out.print(str.charAt(lee));

        }}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you explain what is not working in your code ? Why two loops ? By the way, you dan't want `le` to be equals to `str.length`, the last `char` is at `str.length() - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn the loops you would need just one:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          String str = "baby";
            for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i +=2) {
                if(i<str.length())
                   System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i-1));
              }
      }
```

You go 2 indexes ahead on each iteration, get both letters and swap them. The check for length is not to go out of bounds because when you go 2 indexes in a row if you have odd length of the string it will happen.

And for a super cool recursive solution:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {         
      printSwapped("baby");
  }

 static void printSwapped(String str) {
     if(str.length()<=1) {
         System.out.print(str);
     }else {
         System.out.print(str.charAt(1));
         System.out.print(str.charAt(0));
         printSwapped(str.substring(2));
     }       
 }
```

Comment: Your first solution misses the edge case of an odd string, but your recursive solution is very cool +1.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the problem with the odd numbers right after I typed it  and editted it :( you always hurry to be the first to help and such errors happen

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy to do using a regex replacement:

```
String input = "baby";
input = input.replaceAll("(.)(.)", "$2$1");
System.out.println(input);

abyb
```

### Demo

If you really wanted to do this with a loop, then use a `StringBuilder` and just takes steps of two as you walk down the input:

```
String input = "baby";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i=0; i < input.length()-1; i=i+2) {
    sb.append(input.charAt(i+1));
    sb.append(input.charAt(i));
}
// edge case: for odd-length inputs, we don't swap the final letter
// but we still add it to the end of the string
if (input.length() % 2 != 0) sb.append(input.charAt(input.length()-1));
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Great solution using titties :) you get my vote on that

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I'd like to think of them as eyeballs :-P

Comment: Bravo on that regex solution, even though it contributes to the widespread delusion that any and every problem can be solved by a regex ;->